# How do I have two code colors in revealjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reveal.js

In reveal.js how can I have two code colors, lets's say one is light and another is dark.
Here is a code with two color codes, I want to change the color of the second one to light:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>reveal.js - Auto Animate</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/reveal.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/theme/black.css" id="theme">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugin/highlight/monokai.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="reveal">
            <div class="slides">
                <section >
                    <pre data-id="code"><code>
                        println("dark color code is fine here.")
                    </code></pre>
                </section>
            <div class="slides">
                <section >
                    <pre data-id="code"><code>
                        println("I want light color code here.")
                    </code></pre>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="../dist/reveal.js"></script>
        <script src="../plugin/highlight/highlight.js"></script>
        <script>
            Reveal.initialize({
                center: true,
                hash: true,
                plugins: [ RevealHighlight ]
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any suggestion or comment is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this would be taking the theme css

```css
pre code.hljs{display:block;overflow-x:auto;padding:1em}
code.hljs{padding:3px 5px}
.hljs{color:#abb2bf;background:#282c34}
```

and scoping the selectors

```css
pre[data-theme="monokai"] code.hljs{display:block;overflow-x:auto;padding:1em}
[data-theme="monokai"] code.hljs{padding:3px 5px}
[data-theme="monokai"] .hljs{color:#abb2bf;background:#282c34}
```

Then the highlights will just work with scoped

```html
<section >
    <pre data-id="code" data-theme="monokai"><code>
        println("dark color code is fine here.")
    </code></pre>
    <pre data-id="code" data-theme="atom-one-light"><code>
        println("light color code is fine here.")
    </code></pre>
</section>
```

This will work with any combination of any number of themes (remember, themes may use bold and italic)

---

There is no easier way, as highlightjs used by revealjs doesn't support multiple themes natively or it would have scoped CSS

---

Here is the complete code (provided by Woeitg):

[image]

```css
    pre[data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs {
      color: #383a42;
      background: #fafafa;
    }
       
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-comment,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-quote {
      color: #a0a1a7;
      font-style: italic;
    }
    
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-doctag,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-keyword,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-formula {
      color: #a626a4;
    }
    
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-section,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-name,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-selector-tag,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-deletion,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-subst {
      color: #e45649;
    }
    
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-literal {
      color: #0184bb;
    }
    
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-string,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-regexp,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-addition,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-attribute,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-meta .hljs-string {
      color: #50a14f;
    }
    
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-attr,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-variable,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-template-variable,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-type,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-selector-class,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-selector-attr,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-selector-pseudo,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-number {
      color: #986801;
    }
    
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-symbol,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-bullet,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-link,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-meta,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-selector-id,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-title {
      color: #4078f2;
    }
    
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-built_in,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-title.class_,
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-class .hljs-title {
      color: #c18401;
    }
    
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-emphasis {
      font-style: italic;
    }
    
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-strong {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    [data-theme="mycolors2"] .hljs-link {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    
    .hljs {
      color: #abb2bf;
      background: #282c34;
    }
    
    .hljs-comment,
    .hljs-quote {
      color: #5c6370;
      font-style: italic;
    }
    
    .hljs-doctag,
    .hljs-keyword,
    .hljs-formula {
      color: #c678dd;
    }
    
    .hljs-section,
    .hljs-name,
    .hljs-selector-tag,
    .hljs-deletion,
    .hljs-subst {
      color: #e06c75;
    }
    
    .hljs-literal {
      color: #56b6c2;
    }
    
    .hljs-string,
    .hljs-regexp,
    .hljs-addition,
    .hljs-attribute,
    .hljs-meta .hljs-string {
      color: #98c379;
    }
    
    .hljs-attr,
    .hljs-variable,
    .hljs-template-variable,
    .hljs-type,
    .hljs-selector-class,
    .hljs-selector-attr,
    .hljs-selector-pseudo,
    .hljs-number {
      color: #d19a66;
    }
    
    .hljs-symbol,
    .hljs-bullet,
    .hljs-link,
    .hljs-meta,
    .hljs-selector-id,
    .hljs-title {
      color: #61aeee;
    }
    
    .hljs-built_in,
    .hljs-title.class_,
    .hljs-class .hljs-title {
      color: #e6c07b;
    }
    
    .hljs-emphasis {
      font-style: italic;
    }
    
    .hljs-strong {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .hljs-link {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    
            <title>reveal.js</title>
    
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/reset.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/reveal.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/theme/black.css">
    
            <!-- Theme used for syntax highlighted code -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin/highlight/mycolors.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="reveal">
                <div class="slides">
                <section >
                    <pre data-id="code" data-theme="mycolors"><code>
                        println("dark color code is fine here.")
                    </code></pre>
                    <pre data-id="code" data-theme="mycolors2"><code>
                        println("light color code is fine here.")
                    </code></pre>
                </section>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <script src="dist/reveal.js"></script>
            <script src="plugin/notes/notes.js"></script>
            <script src="plugin/markdown/markdown.js"></script>
            <script src="plugin/highlight/highlight.js"></script>
            <script>
                // More info about initialization & config:
                // - https://revealjs.com/initialization/
                // - https://revealjs.com/config/
                Reveal.initialize({
                    hash: true,
    
                    // Learn about plugins: https://revealjs.com/plugins/
                    plugins: [ RevealMarkdown, RevealHighlight, RevealNotes ]
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: read the question with my update.thanks

Comment: @Woeitg you are missing SPACES

Comment: Where exactly I miss spaces? Can you edit the question to fix it?

Comment: @Woeitg `[data-theme="monokai"].hljs` means "el with class 'hljs' AND attr data-theme='monokai'", while you need `[data-theme="monokai"] .hljs` which means "el with class 'hljs' BEING CHILD OF el with attr data-theme='monokai'"

Comment: thanks. now I try to fix and run it.